# hibernate double logging

Tags: hibernate

I am working on a project using Spring, hibernate and struts2. Queries and system outs are being logged twice. I do have slf4j-api-1.6.1 and slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1 jars in lib folder.

log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

applicationContext.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- The singleton hibernate session factory -->
 <bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
 </bean>

<!-- Spring's hibernate transaction manager, in charge of making hibernate sessions/txns -->
 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

<!-- So classes/functions with @Transactional get a hibernate txn -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
 <!-- Inject my business services class to the actions -->
 <bean id="services" class="dao.Services" scope="singleton">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <!-- Database connection settings -->
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/ciner</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password" />
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <!--
   Exception was thrown. Thus removed, until fix is found. Enable c3p0
   connection pooling, because hibernate pooling is not prod-ready.
   Apparently connection.provider_class is needed in hibernate 3+
   <property
   name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
   <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property> <property
   name="c3p0.min_size">1</property> <property
   name="c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property> Echo all executed SQL to
   stdout for debugging
  -->
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="format_sql">true</property>
  <!--
   All the entity classes for hibernate to check for annotations here
  -->

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
 <!-- set to false for prod -->
 <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">


 </package>

</struts>
```

Output

```
20:57:23,338 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: 
select
        newhire0_.employee_id as employee1_10_,
        newhire0_.active_status as active2_10_,
        newhire0_.cost_center as cost3_10_,
        newhire0_.credit_training as credit4_10_,
        newhire0_.development_plan as developm5_10_,
        newhire0_.development_session as developm6_10_,
        newhire0_.development_training as developm7_10_,
        newhire0_.employee_market as employee8_10_,
        newhire0_.end_date as end9_10_,
        newhire0_.first_offer_letter_sent as first10_10_,
        newhire0_.hire_date as hire11_10_,
        newhire0_.housing_required as housing12_10_,
        newhire0_.last_review_date as last13_10_,
        newhire0_.last_review_type as last14_10_,
        newhire0_.last_reviewer_name as last15_10_,
        newhire0_.new_hire_first_name as new16_10_,
        newhire0_.new_hire_last_name as new17_10_,
        newhire0_.lob_id as lob18_10_,
    from
        ciner.new_hire newhire0_ 
    order by
        newhire0_.hire_date,
        newhire0_.lob_id,
        newhire0_.new_hire_last_name,
        newhire0_.new_hire_first_name
20:57:24,458 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: 
select
        newhire0_.employee_id as employee1_10_,
        newhire0_.active_status as active2_10_,
        newhire0_.cost_center as cost3_10_,
        newhire0_.credit_training as credit4_10_,
        newhire0_.development_plan as developm5_10_,
        newhire0_.development_session as developm6_10_,
        newhire0_.development_training as developm7_10_,
        newhire0_.employee_market as employee8_10_,
        newhire0_.end_date as end9_10_,
        newhire0_.first_offer_letter_sent as first10_10_,
        newhire0_.hire_date as hire11_10_,
        newhire0_.housing_required as housing12_10_,
        newhire0_.last_review_date as last13_10_,
        newhire0_.last_review_type as last14_10_,
        newhire0_.last_reviewer_name as last15_10_,
        newhire0_.new_hire_first_name as new16_10_,
        newhire0_.new_hire_last_name as new17_10_,
        newhire0_.lob_id as lob18_10_,
    from
        ciner.new_hire newhire0_ 
    order by
        newhire0_.hire_date,
        newhire0_.lob_id,
        newhire0_.new_hire_last_name,
        newhire0_.new_hire_first_name
20:57:24,962 INFO  [STDOUT] FA/2010, Chief Information Officer, John Doe1
20:57:24,962 INFO  [STDOUT] SP/2010, Unknown, John Doe2
20:57:24,962 INFO  [STDOUT] SP/2010, Chief Information Officer, John Doe3
20:57:24,990 INFO  [STDOUT] FA/2010, Chief Information Officer, John Doe1
20:57:24,990 INFO  [STDOUT] SP/2010, Unknown, John Doe2
20:57:24,991 INFO  [STDOUT] SP/2010, Chief Information Officer, John Doe3
```

Comment: Can you show a representative output to get an idea? Also, how is logging configured for Spring? Do you still use Commons Logging for Spring?

Comment: Did you configure your log4j appender not to be additive?

Comment: Nice to know that I'm not the only one facing the double logging issue.... :)

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say without seeing the code, but I would guess your are configuring your logger twice.  Are you sure you don't have

```
BasicConfigurator.configure()
```

*anywhere* in your code?

Comment: @Pascal - I have added my output above. I don't think I have logging configured for Spring. I do have commons jar in my lib folder though.
  
@binil - How do i configure log4j appender not to be additive?
  
@hvgotcodes - No, i dont.
  
Is there anyother configuration you want me to post?

Answer (score 0):

Nishant, try:

```
log4j.additivity.org.hibernate=false
```